# Cannot create procedure

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

The following Java code (using Connector/J to create a stored procedure on MySQL 5.0) does not execute successfully.

```
statement.execute("DELIMITER //\nCREATE PROCEDURE abdt (std INT)\nBEGIN\nSELECT att_begin, att_end FROM abdt WHERE student_id = std;\n\nEND;\n//\nDELIMITER ;");
```

Could you please try to explain me why like this works?

```
String query="";
    query = "CREATE PROCEDURE process_something (IN input_id BIGINT)\n";
    query+= "BEGIN\n";
    query+= "DECLARE num_rows, cnt, last_id INT DEFAULT 0;\n";
    query+= "DECLARE indx_found INT DEFAULT 0;\n";
    query+= _mainStoreProcedureBody;
    query+= "END\n";
    Connection con= session.connection();
    Statement st= con.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Any possible help will be very appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You can't execute multiple statements at once. Remove the delimiter part. These are extra statements

Comment: I thought, given the question, that this was related to some performance optimization problem. BTW, what is this DELIMITER thing?

Comment: It's too much java code in a mysql-specific question. You want to discuss mysql performance - then you need to remove all java and only leave pure mysql statements.

Comment: @Leo: In MySQL you need to change the delimiter. Otherwise the DB thinks your trigger definition ends at the first `;` which would be incomplete.

Comment: Thank you all for the insights but this is a java code and the intention is to run the statement.execute above. It's just a matter of removing the DELIMITER from the code? Like this for example:

Comment: Forgot to add this, Something like this will work? ----> statement.execute("CREATE PROCEDURE abdt (std INT)\nBEGIN\nSELECT att_begin, att_end FROM abdt WHERE student_id = std;\n\nEND;");

Comment: @Leo the above statement will do the trick?